# Can not browse anything after connecting to a tunnel

Tags: android, dns, android-networking, dnsmasq, android-vpn-service

So, I was going through the guide of connecting to a VPN using an applicaton from here [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn)
. What I really want is to make my own VPN app by using free DNS available on the internet. Because I want to have DoH (DNS over Https)and full security. So, I want CleanBrowsing to be my DNS. (I know there is already an app for it but I want to do it from scratch). So I went to this [CleanBrowsing DNS GUIDE](https://cleanbrowsing.org/guides/android#manual). I am using the follwing free filter provided by them

`family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org`

So, I am able to connect my tunnel to the server but when I open a browser it does not do anything. here is the mini version of the configuration here.

```
final SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org", 53);
```

VpnService.Builder builder = mService.new Builder();

```
    builder.addAddress("10.1.10.1", 32);
    builder.addDnsServer("185.228.168.168");
    builder.addDnsServer("9.9.9.9");
    builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
    builder.setMtu(1000);
```

My complete file looks like this

```
 public ToyVpnConnection(final VpnService service, final int connectionId,
                            final String serverName, final int serverPort, final byte[] sharedSecret,
                            final String proxyHostName, final int proxyHostPort, boolean allow,
                            final Set<String> packages) {
        mService = service;
        mConnectionId = connectionId;

        mServerName = serverName;
        mServerPort = serverPort;
        mSharedSecret = sharedSecret;

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(proxyHostName)) {
            mProxyHostName = proxyHostName;
        }
        if (proxyHostPort > 0) {
            // The port value is always an integer due to the configured inputType.
            mProxyHostPort = proxyHostPort;
        }
        mAllow = allow;
        mPackages = packages;
    }

    /**
     * Optionally, set an intent to configure the VPN. This is {@code null} by default.
     */
    public void setConfigureIntent(PendingIntent intent) {
        mConfigureIntent = intent;
    }

    public void setOnEstablishListener(OnEstablishListener listener) {
        mOnEstablishListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(getTag(), "Starting");

            // If anything needs to be obtained using the network, get it now.
            // This greatly reduces the complexity of seamless handover, which
            // tries to recreate the tunnel without shutting down everything.
            // In this demo, all we need to know is the server address.
            final SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org", 53);

            // We try to create the tunnel several times.
            // TODO: The better way is to work with ConnectivityManager, trying only when the
            // network is available.
            // Here we just use a counter to keep things simple.
//            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 10; ++attempt) {
            // Reset the counter if we were connected.
            if (run(serverAddress)) {
//                    attempt = 0;
            }

//                 Sleep for a while. This also checks if we got interrupted.
//                Thread.sleep(3000);
//            }
            Log.i(getTag(), "Giving up");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(getTag(), "Connection failed, exiting", e);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ToyVpnConnection";

    private boolean run(SocketAddress server)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, IllegalArgumentException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor iface = null;
        boolean connected = false;
        // Create a DatagramChannel as the VPN tunnel.
        try (DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open()) {

            // Protect the tunnel before connecting to avoid loopback.
            if (!mService.protect(tunnel.socket())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
            }

            // Connect to the server.
            tunnel.connect(server);
            Log.d(TAG, "run: connected to the tunnel");

            // For simplicity, we use the same thread for both reading and
            // writing. Here we put the tunnel into non-blocking mode.
            tunnel.configureBlocking(false);

            // Authenticate and configure the virtual network interface.
            iface = configure("");

            // Now we are connected. Set the flag.
            connected = true;

            // Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(iface.getFileDescriptor());

            // Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(iface.getFileDescriptor());

            // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
            ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);

            // Timeouts:
            //   - when data has not been sent in a while, send empty keepalive messages.
            //   - when data has not been received in a while, assume the connection is broken.
            long lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long lastReceiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // We keep forwarding packets till something goes wrong.
            while (true) {
                // Assume that we did not make any progress in this iteration.
                boolean idle = true;

                // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
                int length = in.read(packet.array());
                if (length > 0) {
                    // Write the outgoing packet to the tunnel.
                    packet.limit(length);
                    tunnel.write(packet);
                    packet.clear();

                    // There might be more outgoing packets.
                    idle = false;
                    lastReceiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

                // Read the incoming packet from the tunnel.
                length = tunnel.read(packet);
                if (length > 0) {
                    // Ignore control messages, which start with zero.
                    if (packet.get(0) != 0) {
                        // Write the incoming packet to the output stream.
                        out.write(packet.array(), 0, length);
                    }
                    packet.clear();

                    // There might be more incoming packets.
                    idle = false;
                    lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

                // If we are idle or waiting for the network, sleep for a
                // fraction of time to avoid busy looping.
                if (idle) {
                    Thread.sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_MS);
                    final long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (lastSendTime + KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_MS <= timeNow) {
                        // We are receiving for a long time but not sending.
                        // Send empty control messages.
                        packet.put((byte) 0).limit(1);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                            packet.position(0);
                            tunnel.write(packet);
                        }
                        packet.clear();
                        lastSendTime = timeNow;
                    } else if (lastReceiveTime + RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS <= timeNow) {
                        // We are sending for a long time but not receiving.
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Timed out");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e(getTag(), "Cannot use socket", e);
        } finally {
            if (iface != null) {
                try {
                    iface.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getTag(), "Unable to close interface", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }

    private ParcelFileDescriptor handshake(DatagramChannel tunnel)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // To build a secured tunnel, we should perform mutual authentication
        // and exchange session keys for encryption. To keep things simple in
        // this demo, we just send the shared secret in plaintext and wait
        // for the server to send the parameters.

        // Allocate the buffer for handshaking. We have a hardcoded maximum
        // handshake size of 1024 bytes, which should be enough for demo
        // purposes.
        ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        // Control messages always start with zero.
        packet.put((byte) 0).put(mSharedSecret).flip();

        // Send the secret several times in case of packet loss.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            packet.position(0);
            tunnel.write(packet);
        }
        packet.clear();


        return configure(new String());

        // Wait for the parameters within a limited time.
//        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HANDSHAKE_ATTEMPTS; ++i) {
//            Thread.sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_MS);
//
//            // Normally we should not receive random packets. Check that the first
//            // byte is 0 as expected.
//            int length = tunnel.read(packet);
//            if (length > 0 && packet.get(0) == 0) {
//
//            }
//        }
//        throw new IOException("Timed out");
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private ParcelFileDescriptor configure(String parameters) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
        VpnService.Builder builder = mService.new Builder();


        builder.addAddress("10.1.10.1", 32);
//        builder.addAddress("185.228.148.168", 32);
//        builder.addAddress("192.168.1.1", 24);

        builder.addDnsServer("185.228.168.168");
        builder.addDnsServer("9.9.9.9");
        builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
        builder.setMtu(1000);


        // Create a new interface using the builder and save the parameters.
        final ParcelFileDescriptor vpnInterface;


        try {
            builder.addDisallowedApplication("com.example.android.toyvpn");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w(getTag(), "Package not available: " + "packageName", e);
        }

//        for (String packageName : mPackages) {
//            try {
//                if (mAllow) {
//                    builder.addAllowedApplication(packageName);
//                } else {
//
//                }
//            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
//
//            }
//        }


        builder.setSession(mServerName).setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mProxyHostName)) {
//            builder.setHttpProxy(ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy(mProxyHostName, mProxyHostPort));
        }
        synchronized (mService) {
            vpnInterface = builder.establish();


            if (mOnEstablishListener != null) {
                mOnEstablishListener.onEstablish(vpnInterface);
            }
        }
        Log.i(getTag(), "New interface: " + vpnInterface + " (" + parameters + ")");
        return vpnInterface;
    }

    private final String getTag() {
        return ToyVpnConnection.class.getSimpleName() + "[" + mConnectionId + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the route address:

```
builder.addRoute("10.1.10.0", 32);
```